# Need help using RegEx to Replace lines

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need to do a Find & Replace (NOT in Code, in the VB IDE or a Text Editor).

I need to take:

> IsNumeric(CInt(whatevertextishere))

and change it to

> IsNumeric(whatevertextwasthere)

I've tried:

```
IsNumeric\(CInt\(.*\)\)
```

for find, and `IsNumeric($1)` for the replace, the find works, but the replace does not. It simply replaces it with the literal text `IsNumeric($1)`, instead of putting the matched text, which should be the "whatevertextishere".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined a capture group in the regex (with unescaped parentheses):

```
IsNumeric\(CInt\((.*)\)\)
```